# AdalJs - How to disable silent renewing Tokens

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, access-token, adal, adal.js

I'm working on applying a custom company security policy in my company's application. 
I use the AdalJs library and I see that even if I apply the my Azure policy to the AD application, because of the silent renewing tokens, I'm not able to comply with the policy requirements.

Is there a parameter to set in AdalJs library to disable the Renewing Tokens?
If not, I'll be forced to modify the library, but it is not what I'd like to do.

Thank u in advance.
OaicStef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such parameter we can disable token renewing. If you have a common scenario require this feature, I suggest that you submit the feedback from [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues).

And if it is not a common scenario, you may need to modify the source code. For example, you can modify the [acquireToken](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/adal.js#L508) function to remove the relative code about **_renewToken** and modify it based on your special requirement.